# Dominos on a checkerboard

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, checkerboard

What's the maximal number of dominos (2x1 tiles) that can be placed on a checkerboard (8x8 square) so that every domino covers exactly 2 squares of the checkerboard and no two dominos form a 2x2 square?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like:

> 31 dominos can be placed  
>  
>  <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub>

Thanks to @Gamow's comment, this number's maximality can be proved
by self-contradiction of the assumption that it is not maximal.
Any more dominos would cover all 64 squares.

**Assumption to be disproved:** All squares can be covered with dominos.

A. As the top left corner must be covered, start with a horizontal domino
   there.  (Every other possible corner domino is equivalent to this
   by rotation and reflection.)  From here on:

> Successive placements of a diagonal series of dominos
>  are forced to form a descending herringbone staircase in order to prevent
>  a 2x2 square from being formed in combination with each previous domino.
>  
>
>  B. The domino that neighbors A along the left edge must be vertical.
>  
>
>  C. The inside corner formed by A and B must be covered by
>     a horizontal domino.
>  
>
>  D −  M. Likewise,
>     until a horizontal domino-shaped hole at the bottom right corner,
>     if filled, would form a 2x2 square
>     with M.
>  [image] 
>  [image] 
>  [image]

Therefore the top left corner cannot be covered,
which negates the assumption
and proves that a 32-domino solution is impossible.

**Further reading,** courtesy of @Fimpellizieri's comment:


[Conway's Tiling Groups <sub>PDF</sub>](http://www.cimat.mx/ciencia_para_jovenes/pensamiento_matematico/thurston.pdf)
[and height functions]
– W. P. Thurston

[Tiling with Polyominoes and Combinatorial Group Theory <sub>PDF</sub>](http://olympiads.mccme.ru/lktg/2009/4/articles/conway.pdf)
– J. H. Conway & J. C. Lagarias

[Domino Tilings of the Torus <sub>PDF</sub>](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06354v1)
[and the plane]
[Abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06354)
– F. de Souza Lima Impellizieri

Comment: I think that 31 cannot be beaten: Suppose that there is a solution with 32, and consider the domino in the upper left corner. Then the position of the two dominoes directly below it is enforced.  You may continue like this, and argue that there is a staircase going towards the lower right corner. In the very end, you generate a 2x2 square. Contradiction.

Comment: Posted an answer with this and then saw your comments.  Mine doesn't have very nice graphics, so I've deleted it to let one of you make a prettier one.

Comment: @hmmn: Just add the argument to your solution. The hard part of the puzzle is coming up with the 31-piece solution.

Comment: @Gamow This is correct! My MSc dissertation is on domino tilings of the torus. In fact, any two distinct tilings of a finite simply-connected planar region can be joined by a sequence of flips, where a flip is a move that exchanges two dominos forming a $2\times 2$ square by the only other configuration. In particular, if a simply-connected planar region admits more than one domino tiling (and the checkerboard admits many of them), than each of its tilings necessarily admits a flip (and thus contains a tiled $2 \times 2$ square).

Comment: If you're into domino tilings, you can learn some more about height functions (introduced by Thurston [here](http://www.cimat.mx/ciencia_para_jovenes/pensamiento_matematico/thurston.pdf)). Coincidentally, with the missing domino the tiling you chose is the 'highest' (or 'lowest'). I'll shamelessly plug my MSc dissertation [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06354): it's on domino tilings of the torus, but it also discusses the planar case. For more general tilings, Conway wrote a nice paper involving group theory [here](http://olympiads.mccme.ru/lktg/2009/4/articles/conway.pdf).

Comment: Thanks again, @Gamow, laying out your proof with pictures was more satisfying than the solution

Comment: Which app did you use in order to make the pictures @humn?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva, sorry to take so long to reply.  It was just mcPaint on terminal, not phone.  McPaint, to editorialisze, has almost no official documentation but works well for those inside, of whom i'm not, and for those outside who know how to look behind the curtain.